# how to treat dictionary as an "whole thing" when using itertools?

Tags: python, dictionary, generator, permutation, python-itertools

```
from itertools import product

a = [1, 2, 3]
dict1 = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}
dict2 = {"r": 4, "s": 5, "t": 6}

for i in product(a, dict1, dict2):
print(i)
```

and I got:

```
(1, 'x', 'r')
(1, 'x', 's')
(1, 'x', 't')
(1, 'y', 'r')
(1, 'y', 's')
(1, 'y', 't')
(1, 'z', 'r')
(1, 'z', 's')
(1, 'z', 't')
(2, 'x', 'r')
(2, 'x', 's')
(2, 'x', 't')
(2, 'y', 'r')
(2, 'y', 's')
(2, 'y', 't')
(2, 'z', 'r')
(2, 'z', 's')
(2, 'z', 't')
(3, 'x', 'r')
(3, 'x', 's')
(3, 'x', 't')
(3, 'y', 'r')
(3, 'y', 's')
(3, 'y', 't')
(3, 'z', 'r')
(3, 'z', 's')
(3, 'z', 't')
```

But I want to get these instead:

```
(1, {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}, {"r": 4, "s": 5, "t": 6})
(2, {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}, {"r": 4, "s": 5, "t": 6})
(3, {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}, {"r": 4, "s": 5, "t": 6})
```

How can I do this? Maybe I should use another function instead of `product` in this case? Please kindly help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is, that itertools.product will return all product for each element of the iterables provided, so you could get a similar result to your expected result by wraping the two dicts into another iterable:

```
for i in list(product(a, [(dict1, dict2)])):
    print(i)

(1, ({'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'r': 4, 's': 5, 't': 6}))
(2, ({'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'r': 4, 's': 5, 't': 6}))
(3, ({'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'r': 4, 's': 5, 't': 6}))
```

The ouput is similar to what you asked for, but the dictionaries are wrappen inside a tupel.

Answer (score 3):

Your requested output looks like you printed some tuples:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
dict1 = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}
dict2 = {"r": 4, "s": 5, "t": 6}
for n in a:
    print( (n, dict1, dict2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This resembles what you ask for:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
dict1 = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}
dict2 = {"r": 4, "s": 5, "t": 6}
[[e, dict1, dict2] for e in a]

[[1, {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'r': 4, 's': 5, 't': 6}],
 [2, {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'r': 4, 's': 5, 't': 6}],
 [3, {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'r': 4, 's': 5, 't': 6}]]
```

The key thing to note is that you really only want to iterate over `a`, since `dict1` and `dict2` are just content you are copying wholesale.